# Continuous square integrable martingales and family of stopping paths

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, uniform-integrability

I have the following question and I'm not sure of the solution that I've been given:

"Show that for an element $M\in\mathcal{M}_c^2$, the family $\{M_T\}_{T\in\mathcal{J}_a}$ is uniformly integrable for any $a>0$"

By definition I have that $\mathcal{J}_a = \{\text{T a stopping time and} \mathbb{P}(T\leq a)=1\}$

The solution I have been given is very brief anf I do not understand:

$\mathbb{E}[M_a|\mathcal{F}_T]=M_T$

$\mathbb{E}[M_a^2|\mathcal{F}_T]\geq M_T^2$

Then use something like Chebyshev

I am completely confused by this answer, could somebody shed some light on it? Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? The two statements follow from the optional stopping theorem and the fact that $(M_t)_t$ is a martingale and $(M_t^2)_t$ a submartingale.

Comment: I am not aware of the optional stopping theorem, this was not in our notes. Could you explain what this theorem is?

Comment: Perhaps you know the optional sampling theorem? If not then give it a try and google it.

Answer (score 1):

Let us admit that $$\tag{*}\mathbb{E}[M_a|\mathcal{F}_T]=M_T.$$ Then 
$$
\left\lvert M_T\right\rvert\leqslant \mathbb{E}\left[\left\lvert M_a\right\rvert|\mathcal{F}_T\right]
$$
and you probably now that for each non-negative integrable random variable $Y$ on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Pr)$, the family $\left\{\mathbb E\left[Y\mid \mathcal G\right],\mathcal G\mbox{ is a sub sigma-algebra of }\mathcal F\right\}$ is uniformly integrable.

In order to prove (*), you can try to start with the case where $T$ has finitely many values, and then look at $T_n=2^n\lfloor 2^{-n}T\rfloor$.